# Add progress bar (verbose) when creating gensim dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, text, progress-bar, gensim

I want to create a [gensim dictionary](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/dictionary.html) from lines of a dataframe. The `df.preprocessed_text` is a list of words.

```
from gensim.models.phrases import Phrases, Phraser
from gensim.corpora.dictionary import Dictionary


def create_dict(df, bigram=True, min_occ_token=3):

    token_ = df.preprocessed_text.values
    if not bigram:
        return Dictionary(token_)
    
    bigram = Phrases(token_,
                     min_count=3,
                     threshold=1,
                     delimiter=b' ')

    bigram_phraser = Phraser(bigram)

    bigram_token = []
    for sent in token_:
        bigram_token.append(bigram_phraser[sent])
    
    dictionary = Dictionary(bigram_token)
    dictionary.filter_extremes(no_above=0.8, no_below=min_occ_token)
    dictionary.compactify() 
    
    return dictionary
```

I couldn't find a progress bar option for it and the [callbacks](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/callbacks.html) doesn't seem to work for it too. Since my corpus is huge, I really appreciate a way to show the progress. Is there any?

Comment: You can use [`tqdm`](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/) on the iterable you want to cycle through

Comment: This `Dictionary(bigram_token)` part is getting done long, not a visible loop.

Comment: I don't think that you can do much about it. The callbacks you linked cannot be used with `Dictionary`; you can, however, use the parameter `prune_at` in the constructor, and pass a value lesser than 2e6 (the default value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend against changing `prune_at` for monitoring purposes, as it changes the behavior around which bigrams/words are remembered, possibly discarding many more than is strictly required for capping memory usage.

Wrapping `tqdm` around the iterables used (including the `token_` use in the `Phrases` constructor and the `bigram_token` use in the `Dictionary` constructor) should work.

Alternatively, enabling `INFO` or greater logging should display logging that, while not as pretty/accurate as a progress-bar, will give some indication of progress.

Further, if as shown in the code, the use of `bigram_token` is only to support the next `Dictionary`, it need not be created as a full in-memory `list`. You should be able to just use layered iterators to transform the text, & tally the `Dictionary`, item-by-item. EG:

```py
    # ...
    dictionary = Dictionary(tqdm(bigram_phraser[token_]))
    # ...
```

(Also, if you're only using the `Phraser` once, you may not be getting any benefit from creating it at all - it's an optional memory optimization for when you want to keep applying the same phrase-creation operation without the full overhead of the original `Phrases` survey object. But if the `Phrases` is still in-scope, and all of it will be discarded immediately after this step, it *might* be just as fast to use the `Phrases` object directly without ever taking a detour to create the `Phraser` - so give that a try.)